# Heroku deployment issue at node installArchSpecificPackage

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

**(Story)**
So my MERN app works fine on localhost and all paths and json files have been taken care of... proxy, scrips, NODE_ENV, etc... then this new dumb error showed up. I have been trying to get this to work for a month. My file structure wasn't right before and I still got it to deploy by changing the deployment paths but the server was giving a 404 for the axios calls to MongoDB Atlas using Express.

So I put the whole thing together in the right file structure, set the environment variable for ATLAS_URI and after resolving a ton of errors I am stuck on this last one, hopefully. Please help me get rid of it.

**(Problem)**
Not able to deploy on heroku. It's working fine locally.

Error Log after doing **git push heroku master**

```
Total 4619 (delta 1796), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  ^8.15.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   ^6.4.1
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version ^8.15.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.17.0
remote:        Bootstrapping npm ^6.4.1 (replacing 6.13.4)...
remote:        npm ^6.4.1 installed
remote:        
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
remote:        Module installation may take longer for this build
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:        
remote:        > node@8.15.0 preinstall /tmp/build_a457d1d9/node_modules/node
remote:        > node installArchSpecificPackage
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_a457d1d9/node_modules/node/node_modules/.bin/node: 1: /tmp/build_a457d1d9/node_modules/node/node_modules/.bin/node: �����H: not found
remote:        /tmp/build_a457d1d9/node_modules/node/node_modules/.bin/node: 2: /tmp/build_a457d1d9/node_modules/node/node_modules/.bin/node: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
remote:        module.js:550
remote:            throw err;
remote:            ^
remote:        
remote:        Error: Cannot find module 'node-linux-x64/package.json'
remote:            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
remote:            at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
remote:            at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_a457d1d9/node_modules/node-bin-setup/index.js:18:27)
remote:            at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
remote:            at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
remote:            at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
remote:            at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! node@8.15.0 preinstall: node installArchSpecificPackage
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the node@8.15.0 preinstall script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I'm new to this. Please tell me exactly what to do without much jargon. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out how to do this. Just delete the node_modules folder in the source (server.. not client) directory and try again. It should work like a charm...

Found it here [Error while pushing to Heroku: Cannot find module 'node-linux-x64/package.json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56757471/error-while-pushing-to-heroku-cannot-find-module-node-linux-x64-package-json)
Thanks guys